# Order of operation Inner Join and Where clause performance in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, rdbms

Is there any Performance problem to use operation in miss order?

Like
1. All Inner join first then all where condition later.

```
    select * from
    t1
    inner join t2 on t1.t2Id = t2.Id
    inner join t3 on t1.t3Id = t3.Id
    inner join t4 on t2.t4Id = t4.Id
    where 
    t1.Id in (1,2,3,4,5)
    and t2.Id in (1,2,3,4,5,6,7)
    and t3.Name like '%a'
```

2. All table with Respective Where and then Inner join

```
 select * from
    (select * from t1 where t1.Id in (1,2,3,4,5)) a
    inner join (select * from t2 where t2.Id in (1,2,3,4,5,6,7)) a1 on a.t2Id = 
    a.Id
    inner join (select * from t3 where t3.Name like '%a') a2 on a.t3Id = a2.Id
    inner join t4 on a1.t4Id = t4.Id
```

It may effect on query Performance?

3. Also Order of Where Condition?

   Like

   ```
   select * from t1
   inner join t2 on t1.t2Id = t2.Id
   where t1.t2Id in (1,2,3,4,5,6)
   and t2.t3Id in (1,2,3,4,5)
   ```

Comment: Did you test it? What did you get as metrics? Which one ran faster?

Comment: Yes I tested It with small Number of Records. Also Tried with many records but I did not get major difference.

Comment: Read intros to relational & DBMS-specific query optimization/implementation, write the most straightforward queries you can until you have more experience. Then read entire books. These queries are all simply optimized. If you had read some of the zillion questions about simple query optimizations you would see they all merit this same comment, ie the same answer, duplicated below. There is no "best" in engineering until you define what *you* mean by it.

Answer (score 3):

A SQL query goes through three phases when it is run:

1. The query is parsed (and the various references are looked up).
2. The execution plan is created, with an optimization phase based on what the query needs to accomplish.
3. The query plan is execution.

As a result of the optimization, the way you write the query often has less effect on the performance than you might think.  Lots of people have worked very hard on figuring out the best way to optimize queries -- and there are probably lots of things that you are not even aware of (such as different join algorithms, join ordering, pushing down expression evaluations, and so on).

For your examples, the SQL Server optimizer should produce the same execution plans.  The engine is smart enough to realize that these are really doing the same thing.

Note:  This is not true of all query engines.  Some have pretty poor optimizers, and there would be differences in performance.